# Extends jade error when compiling via terminal

Tags: bash, pug, extends

please help me with this problem. I have 2 files: `layout.jade`, `index.jade`. `index.jade` looks like:

```
extends ./layout.jade
```

Also, I have script `compile.sh`:

```
PATH_PREFIX=/Users/path_to_project_folder
OBJ="\"{PATH_PREFIX:'$PATH_PREFIX'}\""
jade -P --obj $OBJ index.jade
```

It suppose to compile index.jade and give it JS object `{PATH_PREFIX: '/Users/path_to_project_folder'}`. But it gets error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/runtime.js:231
      throw err;
            ^
Error: Jade:1
  > 1| extends ./layout.jade
    2| 
    3| block body
    4|   div(class="container-fluid")

the "filename" option is required to use "extends" with "relative" paths
    at Parser.resolvePath (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:464:13)
    at Parser.parseExtends (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:483:21)
    at Parser.parseExpr (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:221:21)
    at Parser.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:122:25)
    at parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:102:21)
    at Object.exports.compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:203:16)
    at renderFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/bin/jade.js:184:71)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/bin/jade.js:132:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPD: Also, It's really strange that if I run this command:

```
jade -P --obj "{PATH_PREFIX:'/Users/path_to_project'}" index.jade
```

It works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error means you cannot tell jade where to compile the file it has to be relative so the error its because you are trying

```
jade < index.jade > index.html (as absolute)
```

in this case scenario you better try with

```
jade < index.jade >
```

the rest is history.

or maybe try some automation with http://gulpjs.com/ instead the bash script

Answer (score 0):

if use "extend" or "include", the filename option must be used.

```
--filename "/absulute/path/to/your-file.jade"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the "filename" option doesn't work anymore, use "path" instead, e.g.

```
jade --path "/absolute/path/to/index.jade" < index.jade > index.html
```